# Apache Beam - CassandraIO write Async - 2.6.0 error

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using following libraries for apache beam to run dataflow job to read data from BigQuery and Store/Write to Cassandra.

1. beam-sdks-java-io-cassandra - 2.6.0
2. beam-sdks-java-io-jdbc - 2.6.0
3. beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform - 2.6.0
4. beam-sdks-java-core - 2.6.0
5. google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all - 2.5.0
6. google-api-client -1.25.0

Since beam-sdks-java-io-cassandra > 2.3 version support saveAsync, I have upgraded all my libraries to 2.6.0.

After libraries update, I am getting following error at the time insert/save data to Cassandra.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper.saveAsync(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/apache/beam/repackaged/beam_sdks_java_io_cassandra/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.cassandra.CassandraServiceImpl$WriterImpl.write(CassandraServiceImpl.java:435)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.cassandra.CassandraIO$WriteFn.processElement(CassandraIO.java:493)
```

It looks like it is an issue of ListenableFuture from Gauva and Cassandra Driver.

Comment: I just faced the same exception. Did you find a workaround?

Comment: @MaximKolchin please see my answer below.

Comment: thanks a lot. The apache Beam has fixed this issue in 2.11.0 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-5723?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

Answer (score 2):

I have a workaround for this. Use beam-sdks-java-io-cassandra - 2.4.0.
I'm working on fixing this incl. some other stuff... will update here.

Update: Most likely found the issue. Pushed a fix to [my own fork](https://github.com/srfrnk/beam/commit/6005f8f06e82a0632bc1f3ad324728fcea0677cd). However it might take sometime until this can be made into a PR and released by the guys at Beam... If anyone wants to use the version I built - you can take a look at how [it's done here](https://github.com/srfrnk/beam-playground)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, @srfrnk!